# initWithTarget:self doesn't get my class to call selector

Tags: ios, objective-c

I create a class for dealing with dismissing keyboard

custom class:

tapReconizer.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface tapReconizer : NSObject {
    UIView* myView;
}

-(void) tapreg:(UIView*)view;

@end
```

tapReconizer.m:

```
#import "tapReconizer.h"

@implementation tapReconizer

-(void) tapreg:(UIView*)view {
    myView = view;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer;
    tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTap:)];

    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [myView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
}

- (void)singleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {    
    [myView endEditing:true];
}


@end
```

and in my viewcontorller:

```
tapReconizer* reg = [[tapReconizer alloc]init];
    [reg tapreg:self.view];
```

but it's seems singleTap: doesn't been called.
Can I do this all just in this custom class?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just use this library to dismiss keyboard https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager
It is very simple to use

Comment: Thanks it's an awesome stuff!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `tapReconizer` instance (`reg`) gets deallocated when it goes out of scope at the end of whatever block it is created in.

You need to keep a strong reference to it. The easiest way is probably to make `reg` an instance variable.

FYI - you probably meant to name your class `TapRecognizer`. You misspelled recognizer and it is standard practice to name classes to start with uppercase letters. Method and variable names start with lowercase.

Comment: I change `UIView* myView;`  to `@property (strong,nonatomic) UIView* myView;` for your advice, but it's the same. how to make `reg` an instance variable correctly?

Comment: In your ViewController, declare your variable **reg** as strong variable

Comment: @EthanChou You misread what I stated in my answer. Add a `@property (nonatomic, strong) TapRecognizer *reg;` property to your view controller. You don't need to change anything in your `TapRecognizer` class.

Answer (score 0):

In your View controller

```
tapReconizer* reg = [[tapReconizer alloc]init];
[reg tapreg:self.view];
```

Here reg is getting deallocated, so make it is global for strong.

Declare it in your viewcontroller.h

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) TapReconizer* reg;
```

or in your .h or .m of view controller 
after

```
 @interface ViewController : UIViewController 
 {
 TapReconizer* reg;
 }
```

Hope it will help you.